# PHP + MS SQL Server: nested stored procedures acting differently than when running directly on the database

Tags: php, sql-server, stored-procedures

This is unfortunately going to be a bit vague due that I can't share my company's code so I apologize in advance.

I'm seeing a discrepancy in the way a stored procedure (that calls other stored procedures) stores employees in our MS SQL Server database. When run directly on the database (using my PHPStorm console) when attempting to add any number of employees it adds them all correctly. However, when run through PHP, only a random number are actually inserted. My PHP setup looks similar to:

```php
$con = sqlsrv_connect($host . ',' . $port, [
    "Database" => $database,
    "UID" => $user,
    "PWD" => $password,
    "ReturnDatesAsStrings" => true,
    "CharacterSet" => "UTF-8"
]);

$sql = "EXEC EmployeeAdd '[{ json data here }]'"
$stmt = sqlsrv_query($con, $sql);
```

I also tried the PDO library and saw the same results.

Has anyone had trouble running nested stored procedures using the `sqlsrv` or `PDO` libraries in PHP? If so, what did you do to resolve the issue? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try to execute this procedure using parameters. Of course, the JSON data is also important,  it seems you are parsing the variables (`"EXEC EmployeeAdd '$json'"`).

Comment: @Zhorov I am actually passing variables. The actual code I'm using looks more similar to `$db->exec('EmployeeAdd' [$id, $json])` and the `$db->exec` method looks similar to the above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is fun! We had a handful of `print` statements that caused the issue. Removing them fixed the issue and I was able to import the employees as expected. Thanks for your help @Zhorov.

More information: by default, PHP sets `WarningsReturnAsErrors` to on. Because print statements generate a warning of `01000` with error code `#0`, PHP treats this as an error and immediately halts execution. To fix this without removing `print` statements, you can either:

1. In a PHP script, set

```php
sqlsrv_configure("WarningsReturnAsErrors", 0);
```

2. Update your php.ini to include

```php
sqlsrv.WarningsReturnAsErrors = 0
```

Comment: Yes, the correct configuration for [error and warning handling](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/how-to-configure-error-and-warning-handling-using-the-sqlsrv-driver?view=sql-server-ver15) helps in case of a `PRINT` statements. +1 from my side.